# A more precise hyperref

Tags: hyperref, indexing, hypertarget, makeidx

I'm currently using `hyperref` and `makeidx` to make a hyperlinked index, and it's working great. But right now, the hyperlinks always take me to the top of the page; ideally, I'd like the links to be more precise (taking me directly to the paragraph or table, instead of just the page).

Is this possible with `hyperref` and `makeidx`? If so, how would I do it? If not, what other packages could accomplish this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

First page\index{First}

\lipsum[1-3]

Later on the first page\index{Later}

\newpage
\printindex

\end{document}
```

I would like the "Later" link to go directly to the "Later" paragraph, not to the top of the page.

Comment: Minimal example that produces this effect please

Comment: @daleif Added MWE

Comment: If I understand the workings of `hyperref` correctly, to get a link to go directly to something in the middle of a page, you need an anchor and a label.  I suspect that neither of these is built into the basic indexing mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest, `makeindex` produces an index of pages where \index entries may be found those entries may be on multiple pages or possibly multiple times within a page thus the index combines all entries for a page and accumulates the page numbers for listing later.

When you click on an index numbered entry it primarily only knows the page number thus it could only go to the anchor on that page and the anchor is usually at the start of page (top).

For alternative linking there are many described in the manual such as the Table of Contents (ToC/Outline) and you could add extras there but it would not be of much use for a standard text list or two-way linking.  There are other levels such as "Bookmarks" (named destination) and "Specials" (usually external URL, though they can be used introspectively) however I would recommend you do not use those widely when publishing since for the reader they can become a nest of issues when not done well. For users even TOC (outline) can be problematic when the names are long.

At the simplest level for internal linking

You could build a list or table of hyperlinks

```
\hyperlink{First}  
\hyperlink{Later}
```

these need their target (named destination) to be defined

```
This is the first page, with a \hypertarget{First} 
Later on the first page\hypertarget{Later}
```

These can be two way

```
This is the first page, with a \hypertarget{First}
{\hyperlink{Later}{and link to a target later on.}}  

Later on the first page\hypertarget{Later}{\hyperlink{First}{Top of page.}}
```