# Precise exact back-reference target with nomenclature

Tags: hyperref, nomenclature, back-referencing

I would like to know if there is a way to make the page references in the nomenclature point to the exact place where the `\nomenclature` command has been given (e.g. by assigning a label as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512694)).

More precisely, what I would like is an analogue of [these patches to `backref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54541) for `nomenclature`. I know that there is the `nomeqref` command from nomenclature, but sometimes I introduce notations without having any equation (but possibly within a definition -- this could be an idea for having a precise place to refer to).

Minimal (not really working) example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\usepackage[pageanchor, backref=page, colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\def\pagedeclaration#1{, \hyperlink{nomencl.#1}{page\nobreakspace#1}} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197166
\makenomenclature 

\begin{document}
.
\hypertarget{nomencl.1}
$x$ \nomenclature[1\(X\)]{$X^0$}{my x}
\vspace{10cm}

,
\hypertarget{nomencl.2}
$L$     \nomenclature[1\(L\)]{$L^0$}{my l}
\newpage

s \hypertarget{nomencl.3} t
$v$  \nomenclature[1\(V\)]{$V^0$}{my v}
\vspace{10cm}

...
\hypertarget{nomencl.4}
$b$ \nomenclature[1\(B\)]{$B^0$}{my b}
\newpage


\printnomenclature[2cm]
\end{document}
```

For instance, I want the "page 2" of the `B^0` item in the nomenclature to point out to the `B^0` instead of just the top of page 2.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Possibly related:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492924/a-more-precise-hyperref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way which seems to work, based on [How to add page numbering in nomenclature to link to an arbitrary page with a "label"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512694)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}

\makeatletter
\def\nomlabelref#1{ , \hyperlink{#1}{page\nobreakspace \pageref{#1}}\nomentryend\endgroup}
\def\@@@nomenclature[#1]#2#3#4{%
{}\hypertarget{#4}  %the {} is important!
{}\phantomsection\label{#4}%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193380
 \def\@tempa{#2}\def\@tempb{#3}\def\@tempc{#4}%
 \protected@write\@nomenclaturefile{}%
  {\string\nomenclatureentry{#1\nom@verb\@tempa @[{\nom@verb\@tempa}]%
      \begingroup\nom@verb\@tempb\protect\nomeqref{\theequation}%
        |nomlabelref}{\@tempc}}%
 \endgroup
 \@esphack}
\makeatother

\usepackage[backref=page,pageanchor, colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

    $x$ \nomenclature[1\(X\)]{$X^0$}{my x}{nomenc:X}
    \vspace{10cm}
    
    See \hyperlink{nomenc:B}{here} the definition of $B^0$, on page \pageref{nomenc:B}.\\
    $L$     \nomenclature[1\(L\)]{$L^0$}{my l}{nomenc:L}
    \newpage
    

    $v$  \nomenclature[1\(V\)]{$V^0$}{my v}{nomenc:V}
    \vspace{10cm}
    
    $b$ \nomenclature[1\(B\)]{$B^0$}{my b}{nomenc:B}
    \newpage

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Comment: It could happen that, in combination with other packages, using some symbols as the label/hypertarget doesn not work, e.g. nomencl:B (using `\def\nomlabelref#1{ , #1 \hyperlink{#1}{page\nobreakspace \pageref{#1}}\nomentryend\endgroup}` will print "nomencl: B" with a space, whence the issue). Instead, just use e.g. nomenclB.

Comment: NB: using nomenclature needs to run makeindex with  `makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls -t %.nlg`   in the commands of MakeIndex,  see http://www.xm1math.net/doculatex/nomenclature.html for TexMaker.